# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.By$ById cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I try make a automation test using Page Object with annotation **By** in selenium webdriver, but de Eclipse show-me the following message error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.By$ById cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Follow the code:

Class: **AcertoPerfilTratamentoOs**

```
public class AcertoPerfilTratamentoOs {

    static WebDriver driver;

    By cidade = By.id("cboCidade");
    By tipoOcorrencia = By.id("txtTipoOcorrencia");

    public AcertoPerfilTratamentoOs(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public void camposCidade(String CampoCidade) {
        Select slc = new Select((WebElement) cidade);
        slc.selectByVisibleText(CampoCidade);
    }
    public void campoTipoOcorrencia(String tipOcorrencia) {
        driver.findElement(tipoOcorrencia).sendKeys("reclamação");
    }
}
```

Class: **ValidarEstrategiaAcertoPerfilLancamentoManualTest**

```
public class ValidarEstrategiaAcertoPerfilLancamentoManualTest {

    static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {  
        SelecionarNavegador nav = new SelecionarNavegador();
        driver = nav.iniciarNavegador("chrome", "http://10.5.9.45/BkoMais_Selenium/");
    }

    @Test
    public void logarAplicacao() {      
        try {
            //Login Page
            LogarBkoMaisPage login = new LogarBkoMaisPage(driver);
            login.logar("844502","Bcc201707");

            //Acessar a estratégia
            ProdutoNetEstrategiaAcertoDePerfilLancamentoManual AcertoPerfil = 
                    new ProdutoNetEstrategiaAcertoDePerfilLancamentoManual(driver);
            AcertoPerfil.AcessarEstrategia();

            //Registro Novo
            RegistroNovoCasoPage novoCaso = new RegistroNovoCasoPage(driver);
            novoCaso.registrarCaso();

            //Preenchendo o campo OCORRÊNCIA
            RandowNumber rn = new RandowNumber(driver);
            rn.randomNumber();

            //Preencher Campos da tela Tratamento Os
            AcertoPerfilTratamentoOs po = new AcertoPerfilTratamentoOs(driver);
            po.camposCidade(" ALMIRANTE TAMANDARE ");
            po.campoTipoOcorrencia("reclamação");

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Mensagem de erro: " +e);
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        //driver.quit();
    }
}
```

[ValidarEstrategiaAcertoPerfilLancamentoManualTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRGko.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you what is wrong: `org.openqa.selenium.By$ById cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement`
I'm assuming this is caused by: `Select slc = new Select((WebElement) cidade);`
Try to following instead (assuming Select has a constructor that takes a WebElement: 
`Select slc = new Select(driver.findElement(cidade));`

Comment: You're welcome! For future learning: pay attention to what the error message is telling you. If you don't know what it means, Google it. You'll be able to fix a lot of things yourself that way. And otherwise you can still ask StackOverflow ;)