# java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, casting, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate radio button in selenium web driver using Page object model.
Below is my code explanation:

```
By AutomaticDataLockTimed = By.xpath("//span[@class='ant-radio']//input[@name='automaticDataLock']");

if (!((WebElement) AutomaticDataLockTimed).isSelected()) {
            JSUtil.clickElementUsingBySelector(AutomaticDataLockTimed, driver);
        }
    }
```

and I am getting below error message

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath cannot be 
>   cast to class org.openqa.selenium.WebElement (org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath and org.openqa.selenium.WebElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I have referred this link [java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.By$ById cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304961/java-lang-classcastexception-org-openqa-selenium-bybyid-cannot-be-cast-to-org)

but this link did not answer my scenario.

I think it is due to casting problem in my if statement but I cannot fix.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call `.isSelected()` on `AutomaticDataLockTimed`, which is a `By` object, but `isSelected()` is a method on a `WebElement` -- that's where your exception is coming from.

I see that you are trying to cast `By` to `WebElement`, but that's not the right way to solve the issue. You need to use your `WebDriver` instance to locate an element with `AutomaticDataLockTimed` before you can call `isSelected()`:

**EDIT**: This answer has been updated to use `getAttribute("value")` instead of `isSelected()`, as specified by the user. I am leaving answer description as-is to match original problem description.

```
By AutomaticDataLockTimed = By.xpath("//span[@class='ant-radio']//input[@name='automaticDataLock']");

// locate the element using AutomaticDataLockTimed locator
WebElement element = webdriver.findElement(AutomaticDataLockTimed);

if (!element.getAttribute("value").equals("true"))
{
    JSUtil.clickElementUsingBySelector(AutomaticDataLockTimed, driver);
}
```

Remember, you should have started `WebDriver` at the beginning of your script as such:

```
WebDriver webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
   List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(WEBELEMENT);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String str = list.get(i).getAttribute("value");
        if (str.equals("true")) {
            list.get(i).click();
        }
```